# jQuery Regular Expression Problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Iam using one Jquery Library which takes the Regular expression in json format in on file and tries to validate that from file

```
"Studentnumber":{
  regex: "/^[-/@#&$*\w\s]+$/",
  alertText: "* Invalid Student Number"
}, // ...
```

I can use this in  my text box field as follows

```
<input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[Studentnumber]] Textbox">
```

Earlier I used to have JavaScript Regular Expression for the field  such as follows

```
<input type="text" validate="regex" regex='^[-/@#&$*\w\s]+$' name="sno" id="sno">
```

When I use the same regular expression that is used in the JavaScript  for jquery.  It is not validating as the same in JavaScript and giving  inappropriate results. What is the Difference between the two?

Comment: Random thought - `&amp;` vs `&` in your HTML attribute?

Comment: You should probably escape the / in the interior of the regex.

Comment: Also - JavaScript allows you to define a RegExp as `/^[-\/@#&$*\w\s]+$/` (note the lack of quotes), might help as well.

Comment: @gnarf - That wouldn't be valid JSON :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your using backspaces in a string, and want them afterwards, you need to escape them, like this:

```
"Studentnumber":{
  regex: "/^[-/@#&$*\\w\\s]+$/",
  alertText: "* Invalid Student Number"
}
```

Though, I'm not 100% sure after looking at this, it might be 4 backslashes instead of 2, but the reasoning for *why* escapes me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the plugin works with regexp, try removing the quotes or construct a new instance:

```
"regex": /^[-/@#&$*\w\s]+$/
```

or

```
"regex": new RegExp("/^[-/@#&$*\w\s]+$/")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Thanks a lot,Thanks a lot,Thanks a lot,Thanks a lot,Thanks a lot,Thanks a lot,Thanks a lot,Thanks a lot,Thanks a lot.
but what is  the difference in having the double quotes and not having it in j query